# react-cookie vs universal-cookie vs react-cookies

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, jwt

I am using JWT to create and verify tokens and store the token in a cookie. (react front end vs Nodejs backend)

I am confused about the use of react-cookie vs universal-cookie and react-cookies.

What is the difference between these and what is the difference between setting cookies on the back-end vs the front-end?

Comment: how did you store the thokens in a cookie. I've been having this issues. can you help

Comment: I would like to propose another candidate called "js-cookie" in this question.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used any of these packages however, all of those packages wrap native JavaScript methods for a simple use of cookies.
Feel free to pick whichever you feel more comfortable with.

Regarding to your second question, there is no difference between them technically. Cookie is a browser-related feature and it's always handled by the browser.

If you set cookies in the back-end, server will add a cookie header that the browser will read and save it.

If you set them in the front-end, `document.cookie` will be interpreted and cookies get saved by your browser.

Answer (score 1):

A cookie is a piece of information stored in the browser, that automatically gets sent on every request to the associated domain.

The backend can tell the browser to set a cookie using the `Set-Cookie` response header. Or cookies can be set within a javascript context.

**One important thing to note** is that cookies often have the `HttpOnly` flag, which means **they can't be set or read from javascript**, they can only be set (and read) by the server.

This is an important security feature, and one you should almost certainly use if your cookie is a JWT access token. Without the `HttpOnly` flag, you're more vulnerable to exploit from XSS attacks.

You can find some more info on this [here](https://owasp.org/www-community/HttpOnly).